# Application request limit reached for different user access_tokens

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, request, limit, facebook-access-token

My application generates a rest URL for Facebook's Graph API in the following way:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
var restUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=picture,name,id&access_token=" + accessToken
                               }
                              });
```

I have been debugging my application a lot today and now the rest call is returning the following message:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#4) Application request limit reached",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 4
   }
}
```

My understanding is that each user get's an allotted number of rest calls so I tried running the app from a different persons Facebook account. But this didn't help. Can anyone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer on Quora](http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-Facebook-Open-Graph-API-rate-limit), there is a rate limit applied to the IP address as well as the token. So logging in with a different Facebook account wouldn't help if you were still using the same IP address.

In general this wouldn't be a problem, because you typically wouldn't have lots of different users logged in from the same IP, but obviously when testing it can be an issue.

If you're on an Internet connection that doesn't have a fixed IP, you could try disconnecting and then reconnecting to your ISP and hope that you are assigned a new address.

Comment: This is the only answer so I guess I have to take your word for it. I'm not getting anywhere near 600 calls per 600 seconds though. It's becoming a significant hinderance.

Comment: I suspect it's not a fixed limit, and that may be one of the reasons why there is no official documentation of the limits. Have you been able to test with a different IP? Perhaps by connecting through a proxy? That would at least confirm that it is an IP limitation. Also you may still get a better answer once the question gets closer to the top of the featured list.

Comment: Thanks James. I'll try a different IP next time the problem occurs and report back.